# Next js - control back button

Tags: routes, next.js

In the application that I'm working on, I go through a sequence of pages. Once the process is completed and Come to the final page, if I click on browser back, is there a way where I can go to some other url rather than the previous pages?

Comment: The browser's back button will always move backward through the browser's session history. What's the actual use case here? Where would you want it to redirect you to?

Comment: We have three different pages. 1. Home 2. Create Profile 3. Profile. So create profile takes us through series of different pages. And once we create our profile, we are redirected to Profile page. From there if we click back, we should go to Home screen rather than Create Profile screen

Comment: In that case @Alokp's answer should suit your needs.

Comment: Actually, by following @Alokp's answer, we can't really go back in the creating profile series of pages. We should be able to skip these pages completely only after creating the account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `router.replace("/create")` or `<Link href='/create' replace>`

Replace prop in next/link or router.replace will prevent adding a new URL entry into the history stack.
When user open 'Create profile page' it will not be entered in history stack. So, when user create profile,its get redirected to 'Profile Page' and then back button is click,it will get redirected to page which was opened before 'Create profile page'.

Comment: Actually Replace is possible only If don't want the flow. But until the creating profile, we should be able to go back and forth. So Creating Profile should be skipped only when we created profile.